# Common data types for matrices and tables in Java

Tags: java, matrix, data-structures

I'm working on a tool for visualizing objects in Java. This tool provides some standard renderings, and I'd like to include some for matrices and tables.

What are the most used classes for such data? Are there any omnipresent frameworks?
Please list **all** used classes you know, not just the most common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear on what you mean by "visualizing objects", but I usually use `JTable`  to display tables

EDIT: I understand better now what you want. My answer was, accidentally, semi-relavent.

The most common method is to use a 2D array (e.g. int[][]). Another common method is to use a normal Array (int[]) with a field that defines the length of a row, giving a square matrix. Unfortunately there is no standard that I know of for this, but an example can be found here : [Matrix.java](https://github.com/Mithos/Sedenion/blob/97f95b1b2af8e9da221c327b1bc89b79e65ff81b/src/main/java/org/sedenion/complex/Matrix.java)

In the same way as an Array can be used, a Collection can be used. Just replace `int[]` with `java.util.List<E>` or `int[][]` with `List<List<E>>` to create 1D or 2D dynamic lists that can be used in the same way. I've never seen this done, but in theory it could be used.

In terms of other classes that are used for tables, if Java has been connected to a database via JDBC (e.g. many forms of SQL) a `java.sql.ResultSet` may be returned by queries to represent tables in the database.

Finally, for GUI components a table may be represented by some subclass of `javax.swing.table.TableModel`. These are all I can think of at the moment.

EDIT: another two possibilities, A single String with delimiters (e.g. commas and newlines as in CSV) can be used to represent a table.

A class that is not implemented in java but could be used would also be some form of linked grid (like a linked list but in 2 dimensions, as opposed to a linked list of linked lists)

Comment: No, you get me wrong... :) I'm writing code to visualize such stuff, but I must be aware of what kind of objects I should be expecting from the user.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I understand now. I shall update my answer

Answer (score 1):

An x by y array where x is the number of rows and y is the number of columns. This is how I've always represented columns and tables. You can programatically get the number of rows and columns from the text file.

```
//This will make a  x by y matrix or table
int [] matrix = new int [x][y];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        //get the value
        matrix[i][j] = value;
    }
}
```